# Regular expression to match a repetitve pattern one of which should contain atleast a digit

Tags: regex

What should be the regular expression to match a repetitive pattern like:

```
AA12/AA/12/BC
A/BC/CD/8
A1/1/X/7
```

Where the first character must be an alphabet, followed by any number of alphanumeric character, followed by the pattern "/X" repeated one or more times where X is alphanumeric character or multiple alphanumeric characters, and at least one repetition should contain a digit.

Valid patterns:

```
A/B/C/D/1
A/1234/XYSX
PQ123/1
AB/CD1/PQ
```

Invalid Patterns:

```
12/AB/34
AB/CD/XY
AB/CD
```

So far I have come up with :

```
[A-Za-z]\w*(/\w*[0-9]\w*)+
```

Which basically says that the later repetitive part should contain a digit, which is not correct as it is fine if only one repetitive part contains a digit..
Can any body help please?

Comment: Note that `\w` includes the underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though certainly not the most beautiful solution, here is one possibility:

```
[A-Za-z]\w*(/\w+)*(/\w*[0-9]\w*)+(/\w+)*
```

Note that I added in two instances of `(/\w+)*`. Basically I'm just adding in "there can be more occurrences of slash-alphanum that don't require a digit".

Comment: Thanks, modified it a little bit. [A-Za-z]\w*(/\w+)*(/\w*[0-9]\w*)+(/\w+)*

Comment: Updated. Did that work for you?

Comment: Works so far. I will do more tests. I will comment if I have any concerns. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `\w` includes the underscore.